# On scroll function it worked with $(window) but not with $(document), why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a function where I have to hide the sticky footer once it reach an element -> `#line-before-related-article`.
When I use `$(document)` the sticky footer disappears when I start scrolling down, which is not what I want.

When I use `$(window)` the sticky footer disappears before of reaching `#line-before-related-article`, which is almost what I need. I want the sticky footer disappearing ONLY when it reaches the `div` with the id `#line-before-related-article`

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() >= $('#line-before-related-article').position().top) {
        console.log(console.log($('#line-before-related-article').position().top))
        $('.sticky-footer').hide();
    }
});
```

I think my issue will be fix once my function works using `$(document)` properly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The window object carries the scroll property and fires the corresponding event about the browser. As you see on its name, the **document** object refers to the DOM elements from the top to the bottom. 
scrolling the content in the browser does not fire an event on a DOM object!

you have to enable the scrolling feature by playing with **CSS**

here is the explanation from jquery website:
https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

> The scroll event is sent to an element when the user scrolls to a different place in the element. It applies to window objects, but also to scrollable frames and elements with the overflow CSS property set to scroll (or auto when the element's explicit height or width is less than the height or width of its contents).

when your element does not have scrolling feature, it will not carry the scroll event capability.
you have to take care of the CSS code to enable the scroll event.